# Retrieving data using Map from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase database in Map format but I am getting a null pointer exception.I have successfully inserted data using map into my firebase database.

Here is my code:

```
public class Chat extends AppCompatActivity {

  DatabaseReference databaseReference1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("URL");

    databaseReference1.addChildEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Map map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String message = map.get("text").toString();   //ERROR GOES HERE!!
            String userName = map.get("Username").toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: post error log here

Comment: See in my post I have indicated error as comment.

Comment: when you are getting an error while pushing record or at the time of retrieval

Comment: At the time of retrieval...

Comment: did you check your record inserted? on firebase?

Comment: Yes.I checked...

Comment: before calling `toString()` method on `map.get("text).toString` please check the value of your `map`

Comment: Brother, I got the problem solved..removing toString() and declaring my map object as Map<String,String>...

Comment: Anyway thanks brother for your time.. @ Akhilesh

Comment: glad your code works

Comment: can i post an answer ?

Comment: Bro, i don't get your above comment, can you describe more?

Comment: Please add your database structure and the exact data that you want to get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your code at the time of retrieval

```
Map<String, String> map  = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

Instead of

```
Map map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

**Edit:**
You can retrieve list of recording using below code

```
databaseReference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map) postSnapshot.getValue();
            if (map != null) {
                String message = map.get("text");
                String userName = map.get("Username");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: sure just a min

Comment: You can retrieve all the record in single bunch as list

Comment: `ChildEventListener` retrieve record one by one